# designing classes and objects in .net for a restaurant assignment

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have received an assignment at School for creating a Restaurant site. I have to use objects and classes (OOP) for my assignment. I have the foundations of the OOP in .net, but what I don't know is how can I design this assignment to be object-oriented. I don't know how to start it.

The requirement is like this:

The menu has to be saved in a database and retrieved from it. The menu is devided in appetizers, Salades, Main Meal, Pastas, Wines, Beverages, Extras,

If you have a good example about how to design my classes that will be great. 
thanks a lot. I am waiting for some help. Please

**Edit 1**

So we have different menus: `Italian, French, Greek, Turkish, Azian etc`.
Each menu has dishes, drinks, deserts: `Appetizers, Pastas, Salads, wine, etc`

Each dish is made of ingredients

A meal would be like part of a day: breakfast, lunch, dinner. Having different meals a day.

Answer (score 6):

No, I think you need to review the concepts of Object Oriented Design.

A menu **is composed** of different kind of meals.

An appetizer **is a kind** of meal.

A salad **is another kind** of meal.

Comment: drinks and Beverages, just like appetizer or salads can be part of a menu, but they are not meals, right? They are part of a meal. So meals are made of dishes, drinks, etc.

So we have a menu composed of meals.
Meals composed of dishes and drinks.
There are different dishes.

So, which one is an interface and which one is a class? In turn some can be both classes and interfaces. how do you deside in this case?

Comment: OOP is a way to model the real world, depending on how you choose to model it, the design might change. A good design models the problem in a way that's easy to maintain, read and understand, while also providing good performance. There're no rigid rules. A drink can be a kind of meal or a meal can be composed of several "products" and then a drink is just a kind of product.

Comment: In terms of interface vs classes, generally speaking, classes define types of objects while interface model behavior of objects. A class identifies what an object IS while an interface identifies what and object CAN DO.

Comment: A kitchen is part of a house. In itself it is an object, but a kitchen is not a house (not a class), but an interface. if the kitchen is not related to a house then it will be considered as a class (object). So a dish is part of a meal as far as it is related to a menu.

Comment: What I was hoping for was some help in designing and creating my objects. I have a lot of theory here. What I need is real examples. How someone will do it if they were assigned this task.

Comment: Seriously, go back and review all the theory of OOP since you're not really grasping the concept. A kitchen IS a class... classes define "types of things"... so a Kitchen might perfectly be a class, now the kitchen in YOUR house, is an INSTANCE of that class.

Comment: It seems you need a revision of OOP. Please read my comment above carefully, that way you can get something. Sorry but you have just been wasting my time.